# Swift - Calculator - Error: Value of type 'String' has no member 'Int'

Tags: swift, calculator

this is my first ever post. I just joined stackoverflow. I'm doing a calculator for school and followed this tutorial (although I didnt follow his interface): 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJHsdjH2HdY&nohtml5=False

But I think swift has updated since then and I am getting the error " Value of type 'String' has no member 'Int'"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblResult: UILabel!

    var result = Float()
    var currentNumber = Float()

    var currentOp = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        currentOp = "="
        lblResult.text = ("\(result)")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func btnNumberInput(sender: UIButton) {
        currentNumber = currentNumber * 10 + Float(sender.titleLabel!.text!.Int()!)
        lblResult.text = ("\(currentNumber)")

    }

    @IBAction func btnOperation(sender: UIButton) {

        switch currentOp {
            case "=":
                result = currentNumber
            case "+":
                result = result + currentNumber
            case "-":
                result = result - currentNumber
            case "*":
                result = result * currentNumber
            case "/":
                result = result / currentNumber
            default:
                print("error")

        }

        currentNumber = 0
        lblResult.text = ("\(result)")

        if(sender.titleLabel!.text == "=") {
            result = 0
        }

        currentOp = sender.titleLabel!.text! as String!
    }


    @IBAction func btnClear(sender: UIButton) {
        result = 0
        currentNumber = 0
        currentOp = "="
        lblResult.text = ("\(result)")
    }





}
```

Comment: Note that you did not copy the code from the tutorial correctly.

Comment: thank you for pointing it out! ive changed it to @IBOutlet var lblResult: UITextField! now and figured out the Int part, now the simulator just wont show anything (blank white screen) despite having no code errors

Comment: That looks like a completely different problem to me. You could ask a new question, but note that a question *"the simulator just wont show anything"* without any additional information how to reproduce the problem and what you tried to *debug* it will probably be closed as off-topic, compare http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Also worth noting that you should not be force unwrapping optionals in your code. You're just asking for a crash. Please learn how to [properly deal with them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36360605/2976878).